# HTML pages in iPhone apps. Where to start?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c

I'm looking to create a small reference app. It has a UItabBar and 4 views that each load a UITableView which can be drilled down to display, essentially a page of information and pictures, like a book.

If I want to make the page a little more stylised than just using labels and image views, the common consensus seems to be to create HTML pages and load them in a web view.

Being new to this, please could someone give me some direction on where to even begin with this? As I understand it, I essentially need to develop a web page with a text editor, and then what? Actualy upload online and create a public website? It's a little confusing, and as I'm not a developer, a little disheartening to think I'll now have to learn HTML as well as Obj-C to create a simple app.

I'm sure there are some great tools or alternatives out there and if someone could recommend such avenues I'd be incredibly grateful.

Kind regards,

Ryan

Comment: give phonegap http://www.phonegap.com/ a look. PhoneGap is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies and get access to APIs and app stores

Comment: Most developers do NOT use HTML for this - when it comes to iPhone, Obj-C has much more powerful and much more useful methods than HTML (NB: I love HTML, but if you're already writing native code, then it is NOT the right way to do styling - HTML rendering on iPhone is less than perfect, and will cause more problems than it solves)

Comment: @kjy112, PhoneGap looks pretty cool, thanks!

Comment: of course, native is always the clear choice, but if you are doing a simple project and not looking for longevity other options are also good.  Titanium is another one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display HTML pages in a UIWebView you can store them in your bundle and display them from there (so no need to put the pages online). It is best though to stick with the UI controls that Apple provides you with. If you need more customization try subclassing some of the standard controls.

If you customize your UI too much it will just confuse the user and degrade their experience.